# How do I assign a custom search method to a ir.actions.act_window?

Tags: openerp-7, odoo

Basically I want to filter out some records but I need to filter them based on the uid and hr.employee. To do this I currently override the search function of the osv object. But to be able to provide multiple ir.actions.act_window for the same object I need to assign a custom method function for each of those. Can I do that? Or there is a better alternative to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Why don't you add computed fields, to use on the `act_window` domains?

Comment: @DanielReis you can't use domain on a non-stored function field, can you?

Comment: Yes you can: [see](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#fields) the `search` parameter.